# Converting raw binary into Spectrogram

Tags: python, spectrogram

I have been searching and reading the approach of representing raw binaries or executable to a Spectrogram figure in Python. The thing I found was representing an already audio file, as .wav, into spectrogram 
(https://fairyonice.github.io/implement-the-spectrogram-from-scratch-in-python.html)

(https://pythontic.com/visualization/signals/spectrogram)

My understanding that any file in my computer is a list of 0's and 1's. So if I want to represent an executable as a spectrogram, it is important first to define the sampling rate and bit depth. I was thinking of having 8000 samples/second as a sample rate and each sample is 1 byte. Then,  we can represent the generated wave signal and the spectrogram.

Please let me know if I am misunderstanding anything.

Comment: If you treat an executable as if it were a sound file then it will just look like noise, regardless of whether you display it as a spectrogram or anything else. I doubt you will see anything interesting for your efforts. What exactly are you trying to achieve as an end result ?

Comment: I am trying to extract the sepectrogram figures of different executable and apply NN image processing to classify them

Comment: I doubt that will work, but good luck anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Paul, but why would I get a noise when representing the executable as a voice signal?

Comment: Executable code will tend to look like pseudo random data - there are no natural periodicities as there would be in an audio sample. Try playing an executable out of your speakers and you will see (or rather hear) what I mean.